# Can't increase Mac OSX bash shell history length

Tags: macos, bash

I set ~/.bash_profile some time ago to have more than 500 lines length but seems system can't catch this.

Do you know why?

```
> nano -w ~/.bash_profile
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced
HISTFILESIZE=10000000

> history | wc -l
     500
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You also need to set `HISTSIZE=10000000`.

`HISTFILESIZE` determines the number of lines to keep in the history file while `HISTSIZE` determines the number of lines to keep in memory.  Both default to `500`

Execute `echo $HISTFILESIZE $HISTSIZE` before you make the change and then again after.  You should see `10000000 500` first then `10000000 10000000` after.

Comment: is the `export` keyword not required? Something like `export HISTSIZE=1000000`

Comment: @firstpostcommenter Only if you want to make the variable known to processes launched from the shell

Answer (score 26):

You need to **export** `HISTSIZE` and `HISTFILESIZE` environment variables in your `~/.bash_profile` file.

Add following lines in your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
# history size
export HISTFILESIZE=1000000
export HISTSIZE=1000000
```

Answer (score 22):

#### Answer:

All you need to do is set `HISTSIZE` in your bash profile (`~/.bash_profile`). You can leave `HISTFILESIZE` *unset*. This will configure **both** the in-memory history and the file-based history.

```
# Saves 10 million lines in memory and in the bash history file.
HISTSIZE=10000000
```

#### Explanation, additional information.

The problem is HISTFILESIZE only sets the maximum history stored to file when you startup a session. HISTSIZE is what determines how many lines get saved at the end of a session. If HISTFILESIZE is larger than your HISTSIZE, you'll never see more than your HISTSIZE because the file is getting overwritten with HISTSIZE commands (*unless* you set history to append, but that is a separate topic: look up `histappend` in **shell builtin commands** for that).

This is the reason you're seeing no effect. With HISTSIZE at default (probably 500) your history file is always getting overwritten by the most recent $HISTSIZE commands. Anything older (which could potentially grow the list past $HISTSIZE) is wiped away.

For most cases there's no need to set HISTFILESIZE independently of HISTSIZE.

HISTSIZE determines how many lines will get written to the history file. The command list is truncated upon exit, before writing to the history file, keeping N most recent lines. By default, this list overwrites the history file.

HISTFILESIZE determines how large the history file (in lines) can be. The file gets truncated upon startup, keeping N most recent lines. In addition, the history file is potentially truncated whenever HISTFILESIZE is set.

Finally, although it appears to be undocumented, BASH sets HISTFILESIZE based on HISTSIZE if HISTSIZE is set during startup. I've tried this out on macOS, and a few varieties of Ubuntu, and the behavior is consistent. If you set HISTSIZE in a launch file (*not* via the command line by any means), HISTFILESIZE will be set to match. (Try it yourself: set HISTSIZE to some arbitarily large value in .bash_profile, exit and start a new terminal, then `echo $HISTSIZE $HISTFILESIZE` and you'll find them matching.)

As a result, there's no reason to touch HISTFILESIZE unless you want different values, and the uses cases to have different values are rare (and typically involve  more history customization settings to get something useful).

Comment: You are correct Zim. The Bash source code shows that it will just set HISTFILESIZE to HISTSIZE if HISTFILESIZE is unset.

http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/bashhist.c?h=bash-4.3-testing#n284

Comment: @robert Tried this on macOS Catalina v 10.15.7 GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19). I still got only 21 lines worth of history. Can this be overwritten incase of low disc space?

Comment: @ilamengl I don't understand the question... so you edited these variables but it doesn't add more than 21 lines of history?

Are you out of disk space?

Comment: @robert yep was out of disk space :/ should I delete the comment from feb 2. 2022 to keep the thread clean?

Comment: No, you're good, just wanted to know the root cause, ty.