# Make iTerm2 window history larger

Tags: terminal, iterm

In iTerm2 3.1.5 on macOS High Sierra, I want to be able see more of my history as I scroll. Currently the scroll history is not enough for me. How can I increase the amount of data history I see while scrolling upwards?

I tried looking in iTerm2 preferences and changing the magic section for instant replay (on the general tab) but that's not doing it.

Comment: Is the limit in iTerm the same as in Terminal.app?

Comment: Related: [Can't increase Mac OSX bash shell history length](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/246621/251859)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

**You have to set the Scrollback buffer**.  This option is found under *Profiles → Terminal*.

You can either set buffer to the number of lines you want to scroll back to or check the box for "Unlimited scrollback".

[image: Screenshot of Terminal preferences showing the Terminal section of Profiles]

Comment: Just wondering does it affect the performance of the application by changing that settings?

Comment: @YashuMittal Mine is at 10k and I’ve seen no change in performance